# Am using openpyxl it open some xl files and fails to open other xl files with the same format

Tags: python-3.x

Question :
Am using openpyxl python it opens xl file and copy it and paste in another file , however some xl files that i paste in it shows error whenever i add it in the code. i compared the xl files that were opened and those which couldn't opened but they are the same format.

```
x = "\\"
print("loading....")

# opening the source excel file

filename = f"C:\\Users\\xtvl6173\\Desktop\\project{x}{date}TB GAS.xlsx"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]


list = ["114190","114200","114440","115310"]
#1 opening the destination excel file
for i in list:
    filename1 = f"C:\\Users\\xtvl6173\\Desktop\\project{x}GAS_{i}_{date}.xlsx"
    wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
    ws2 = wb2.worksheets[2]

# calculate total number of rows and
# columns in source excel file
    mr = ws1.max_row
    mc = ws1.max_column

# copying the cell values from source
# excel file to destination excel file
    for i in range (1, mr + 1):
        for j in range (1, mc + 1):
        # reading cell value from source excel file
            c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)

        # writing the read value to destination excel file
            ws2.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value


# saving the destination excel file
    wb2.save(str(filename1))
```

error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test1.py", line 31, in <module>
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
File "C:\Users\xtvl6173\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\openpyxl\reader\exc
el.py", line 315, in load_workbook
reader.read()
File "C:\Users\xtvl6173\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\openpyxl\reader\exc
el.py", line 280, in read
self.read_worksheets()
File "C:\Users\xtvl6173\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\openpyxl\reader\exc
el.py", line 266, in read_worksheets
pivot = TableDefinition.from_tree(tree)
File "C:\Users\xtvl6173\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\openpyxl\descriptor
s\serialisable.py", line 83, in from_tree
obj = desc.from_tree(el)
File "C:\Users\xtvl6173\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\openpyxl\descriptor
s\sequence.py", line 85, in from_tree
return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
File "C:\Users\xtvl6173\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\openpyxl\descriptor
s\sequence.py", line 85, in <listcomp>
return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
File "C:\Users\xtvl6173\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\openpyxl\descriptor
s\serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
return cls(**attrib)
File "C:\Users\xtvl6173\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\openpyxl\pivot\tabl
e.py", line 601, in __init__
self.x = x
File "C:\Users\xtvl6173\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\openpyxl\descriptor
s\sequence.py", line 25, in __set__
raise TypeError("Value must be a sequence")
TypeError: Value must be a sequence
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Just to make sure: You have a line break after `filename1` that looks a bit fishy to me?

Comment: i did , it was just uploaded her in a wrong format , this code works very well with some excel sheets and doesn't work with error displayed for the others excel files , i think the problem lies within the excel files format however they are seem the same format to me !